# Refreshing a view?

Tags: java, android

I've got a view which uses an AsyncTask to make a dynamic table. The only trouble is that during this I create some checkboxes, but once the user has checked them I want to disable the box. But due to the dynamic way they were created I can't get the reference to set them disabled.

So here is how I create the buttons in a loop:

```
while(it.hasNext()){
                if(checkStatus(it.next())){
                    myCheckbox.setChecked(true);
                    myCheckbox.setEnabled(false);
                }else{
                    myCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                          public void onClick(View v) {
                            buyU asyncTask = new buyU();
                            asyncTask.execute("value1");
                          }
                    });

                }
}
```

So when the button is pressed my asyncTask runs. But I can't modify the checkbox as I don't have the reference for it. I can't pass a reference I don't think as I'm using the passing parameters to send a string with a few values. So I was thinking the easiest way was to just refresh the entire page for square one again.

What is a good way to do this?

Or alternatively can I pass the button as an object to the asyncTask as well as the string and cast them back to their types on the other end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `Object`, just add an instance variable and a constructor. Since we are executing this from `onClick()`, we'll cast `v` to a `CheckBox`:

```
Checkbox c;

public buyU (CheckBox checkbox)
{
  c = checkbox;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute (Result result)
{
  c.setChecked (false);
  c.setEnabled (false);
}
```

Then call:

```
CheckBox check = (CheckBox) v;
buyU asyncTask = new buyU(check);
asyncTask.execute("value1");
```

If you're *sure* that the  `CheckBox` should be disabled upon a click, you can skip the `AsyncTask` param passing and just set the `CheckBox` to disabled right in `onClick()`.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  ((CheckBox)v).setChecked (false);
  v.setEnabled (false);
  buyU asyncTask = new buyU();
  asyncTask.execute("value1");
}
```

I'd also be weary of that enclosing loop, make sure it's not long running if it's running in the UI Thread.

As usual, Java classes start with a capital letter, `buyU` doesn't fit that specification.

Comment: This is genius, I didn't know you could do this. I knew you could do it on other classes, but for some reason never thought of it with Async. Thanks for all the advice, you're a star!

Comment: Also the loop is running in postExcute in the asyncTask, and a progress dialogue is shown whilst its executing so it shouldn't be a problem to the UI?

Comment: @EricBanderhide If a loop is running in the UI Thread, even if you do have a dialog, you're still blocking that thread. Android should still offer to close the app *if* it's a long running loop. You should do some tests and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks AC, the asyncTask can be cancelled by the user with a press of the back button.